# libssl-dev and libssl1.0.0 on confilcting versions

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

My problem on 12.04lts is that somehow my libssl1.0.0 got upgraded to 1.0.1-4Ubuntu5.17 and my libssl-dev requires 1.0.1-4Ubuntu5.14 apt won't update libssl-dev because libssl1.0.0 was upgraded first.

```
xxx@xxx:~/debian$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libtommath0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 123 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,574 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libssl-dev:
 libssl-dev depends on libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14); however:
  Version of libssl1.0.0 on system is 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.17.
dpkg: error processing libssl-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl-dev
```

Also tried downgrading libssl1.0.0 but got version not found.

```
xxx@xxx:~/debian$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14' for 'libssl1.0.0' was not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just seen this on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 as well. https://db.tt/pjuyZ5LT

Comment: Go back 2 years then run `apt-cache policy libssl-dev   libssl1.0.0` :) . Anyway it seems that one of the repositories was disabled, more specifically the `universe` channel. and possible solution was: Enabling it from `software-properties-gtk`